# arp -s returning The ARP entry addition failed: Access is denied Win10

Tags: ip-address, mac-address, arp

I am on windows 10, adding a static address with cmd

`arp -s 192.168.1.1 xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx`

It returns

`The ARP entry addition failed: Access is denied.`
I am running on administrator